# SwipeUp() on UICollectionViewCell in XCUITest triggers unrelated gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, xcuitest

I'm trying to create XCUITest scripts for an app that consists mainly of a vertically scrolling UICollectionView.  When recording the automation of scrolling through the collection view, the app behaves as expected in the simulator, and the test records the `.swipeUp()` gesture applied to the elements that I touched.

But when I execute the recorded automation, that `.swipeUp()` call triggers a pan gesture recognizer on an unrelated element on screen.  When I experimentally removed the pan gesture recognizer `.swipeUp()` had no effect at all (i.e., no scrolling).

I am hoping someone could either point me towards the cause of this unexpected behaviour and/or suggest an alternative method of scrolling through a UICollectionView in XCUITest

Comment: It is hard to help you since no screenshots or code have been provided...

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively scroll using this method

```
    let startPoint = collectionView.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5))
    let endPoint = collectionView.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 1.0))
    startPoint.press(forDuration:forDuration, thenDragTo:endPoint);
```